# AMD discrete GPU doesn't work, only the motherboard integrated graphics does

Tags: windows-8, ati-mobility-radeon, switchable-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I ensure my Samsung Series 7 is actually using the Radeon switchable graphics?](https://superuser.com/questions/404430/how-can-i-ensure-my-samsung-series-7-is-actually-using-the-radeon-switchable-gra)

I recently installed Windows 8 on my Samsung Series 7 laptop. It's working wonderfully apart from one detail that would be that my AMD Radeon HD 6750m GPU doesn't activate/start when I start playing games. I'm stuck using the Intel HD graphics that's attached to the CPU. I know it's not running because I used GPU-Z to test its load level when running Far Cry 3 - its load level was at zero.

How do I get the AMD GPU to activate/start when playing a game?

I've installed all the latest drivers for all my hardware. I'm not sure if it had to do with the Windows 8 installation, but it has only started since then.

Comment: ive also tried disabling the intel gpu to see if that changed anything but when i went to do the windows index rater it said i was using basic graphics not my amd card

Comment: I edited your question and title to be better understood and to improve it. I hope this is ok with you. You can always edit it again if you feel I've changed too much.

Comment: This is not a gaming question, it's a hardware question, probably better suited on [su].

Comment: @Roxcloud `it said i was using basic graphics not my amd card` sounds like the correct driver is not installed, it would be worth booting into Windows, removing the driver and then reinstalling, ensuring you have the correct driver for your chipset

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a BIOS option to choose whether to boot from the integrated graphics or the discrete? That may have something to do with it. Try booting from the discrete card as the primary display if you have the BIOS option -- my ThinkPad does have such an option but I don't know about the Series 7.

The question and answers to [this other SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/404430/how-can-i-ensure-my-samsung-series-7-is-actually-using-the-radeon-switchable-gra) may prove very helpful to you. According to one answer, a BIOS update to this laptop provided the capability to select, at boot time, which adapter is the primary GPU. By setting the primary GPU to the discrete, I'm sure you'll be able to get it working, even if the "switchable" part isn't working.